# Cross-Browser-Testing - How to configure parallel execution of tests in testng.xml

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, cross-browser, automated-tests, selenium-grid

I want to execute parallel tests on different browsers by using TestNG.
This is my testng.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<suite name="Parallel Tests" verbose="2" parallel="tests" thread-count="4">

        <!--Set test parameters to execute test in Mozilla Firefox browser on Windows platform. -->

        <test name="Linux+firefox Test1" parallel="classes" thread-count="2">

                <parameter name="platform" value="LINUX"/>
                <parameter name="browser" value="firefox"/>
                <parameter name="url" value="http://hh.de/"/>
                <parameter name="version" value="58.0b7"/>

            <classes>
                <class name="suchen.Portalsuche"/>
                <class name="suchen.HVV"/>
            </classes>
        </test>

        <!-- Set test parameters to execute test in Google Chrome browser on Windows platform. -->
        <test name="Linux+chrome Test1" parallel="classes" thread-count="2">

                <parameter name="platform" value="LINUX"/>
                <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/>
                <parameter name="url" value="http://hh.de/"/>
                <parameter name="version" value="62.0.3202.62"/>

            <classes>
                <class name="suchen.Portalsuche"/>
                <class name="suchen.HVV"/>
            </classes>
        </test>

</suite>
```

It launches the first browser (Mozilla Firefox) but it doesn't neither execute the two tests nor launching the second browser(Google Chrome).

Also this is the **code snippet** which I'm currently using for launching those browsers:

```
@Parameters({ "platform", "browser", "url", "version" })
    @BeforeTest(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setup(String platform, String browser, String url, String version) throws MalformedURLException {
        DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setPlatform(org.openqa.selenium.Platform.LINUX);
        System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4stack", "true");
        caps.setCapability("SeleniumTests", "redhat5 && amd64");

        if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {
            System.out.println("Executing on Firefox");
            String Hub = "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub";
            caps = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
            caps.setBrowserName("firefox");
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/opt/geckodriver.exe");

            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(Hub), caps);
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.navigate().to(url);

        } else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
            System.out.println("Executing on Chrome");
            String Hub = "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub";
            caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
            caps.setBrowserName("chrome");
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/opt/chromedriver.exe");
            caps.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

            options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(Hub), caps);
            driver.navigate().to(url);
        }
    }
```

Thanks for your help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the parallel attribute at **test tag level** and reset the thread count at the **suite tag level** to 2.

The testNG xml should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<suite name="Parallel Tests" verbose="2" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">

        <!--Set test parameters to execute test in Mozilla Firefox browser on Windows platform. -->

        <test name="Linux+firefox Test1" >

                <parameter name="platform" value="LINUX"/>
                <parameter name="browser" value="firefox"/>
                <parameter name="url" value="http://hh.de/"/>
                <parameter name="version" value="58.0b7"/>

            <classes>
                <class name="suchen.Portalsuche"/>
                <class name="suchen.HVV"/>
            </classes>
        </test>

        <!-- Set test parameters to execute test in Google Chrome browser on Windows platform. -->
        <test name="Linux+chrome Test2" >

                <parameter name="platform" value="LINUX"/>
                <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/>
                <parameter name="url" value="http://hh.de/"/>
                <parameter name="version" value="62.0.3202.62"/>

            <classes>
                <class name="suchen.Portalsuche"/>
                <class name="suchen.HVV"/>
            </classes>
        </test>

</suite>
```

Comment: I've tried it out but it just launches firefox without executing the tests. Do you have another idea?